# How to suppress nuget restore NU1202 error

Tags: c#

How to Suppress nuget restore error ?

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1202: Package *** is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). *** supports: net48 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8)
```

what if this is my package and I trust it? I give an example. i have solution with projects targeting net 3.1, The error i pasted here was until today only warning. but today i upgraded one project with tests to net6 and this warning became error.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You can't really supress an error like that. The package you are trying to restore just won't work with your project. You need to remove that reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't suppress that; that is a fundamentally incompatible package; .NET Framework and .NET 6 (in this case) are not interchangeable, so you would need that package to (one of):

- have a .NET Core 3 or .NET 5 or above target (possibly multi-targeting .NET Framework and others)
- target .NET Standard 2.0 (possibly multi-targeting others)

Since neither of these is true, you *cannot use that package*. If the package is yours: it isn't *usually* very hard to re-target it to modern .NET; if it isn't yours: contact the package owners.

Comment: what if this is my package and I trust it? I give u an example. i have solution with projects targeting net 3.1, The error i pasted here was until today only warning. but today i upgraded one project with tests to net6 and this warning became error

Comment: @kosnkov it isn't about what ***you*** trust - it is about *what the framework itself offers*; the framework **does not support this**; if it is your library package, then change the package to target the framework or frameworks that you need - perhaps the simplest option here is to multi-target: `<TargetFrameworks>net48;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>` or similar (instead of `<TargetFramework>` - note the `s`) - obviously use your preferred framework options

Comment: @kosnkov btw, you say ".NET 3.1" - there is no ".NET 3.1" - can I assume you actually mean ".NET Core 3.1", aka netcoreapp3.1 ? if so: you still shouldn't be targeting .NET Framework 4.8 (which is what the error message is telling us); to give timeline: .NET Framework 3.0 (2006), .NET Framework 3.5 (2007) ... (skip) , .NET Framework 4.8 (2019) *parallel and very distinct from / different to* .NET Core 3.1 (2019), .NET 5 (2020), .NET 6 (2021), .NET 7 (2022) and .NET 8 (scheduled 2023)

Comment: @kosnkov and if you're not actually using .NET Framework anywhere: *don't target it*